# Are $HADOOP_COMMON_HOME and $HADOOP_HDFS_HOME the same value?

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, distributed-computing, hdfs

I know that `$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME`  should be set to the root path of `Hadoop` directory, but what's the value of `$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME` , is it the same one ?

What's the value should it be ?

Comment: [This](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowToSetupYourDevelopmentEnvironment) help any?

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same ..

There are three main sub-projects within hadoop distribution :

1) hadoop-common - common functionality used by both mapreduce and hdfs like IPC ..

2) hadoop-mapred- mapreduce framework jars

3) hadoop-hdfs - hdfs distributed filesystem jars

Each of them are in different directories . So after you extrace those sub-projects , set 
$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME to the directory where hadoop-common is extracted and set $HADOOP_HDFS_HOME to the directory where hadoop-hdfs is extracted .